# Angular2, Firebase, AngularFire, and graceful logout

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

In my Angular2 app, I use the below to logout and redirect back to login. It works, but I get that terrible error in the console.

I have a toolbar as a header where the signout is located.  In the body I have a component that has a subscription. However, when I signout from the header, the ngOnDestroy is not called. I am assuming that prior to sigout I have to find when ccompenent is loaded, kill the component, then signout.

So how do I find the current competent, kill it so that onDestroy is triggered, then logout? Again I assume this is what is going on.

```
ngOnDestroy() {

  if(this.af_sub){
    console.log('killing home')
    this.af_sub.unsubscribe();
  }
} 

ngOnInit() {


  this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.user = user.auth.providerData[0];
      //console.log(user.auth);
    }
    else {
      this.user = {};
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }); 
}

logout() {
          if (this.user){
            this.af.auth.logout();
          } else {
            //console.log('already logged out');
          }
  } //end
```

logout

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: permission_denied at /accounts/DKesxlT2mkUwwJGCaHBTkPHuDwl2/slugs: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at G (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111598:36) [<root>]
    at Object.G (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111602:86) [<root>]
    at $g (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111586:98) [<root>]
    at Pg.g.wd (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111579:310) [<root>]
    at Ce.wd (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111481:364) [<root>]
    at cd.Xf (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111479:281) [<root>]
    at fd (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111435:464) [<root>]
    at WebSocket.Ia.onmessage (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111434:245) [<root>]
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as _onmessage] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:129332:29) [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:128594:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at WebSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:128788:33) [<root>] 
O @ database.js:54
(anonymous) @ database.js:61
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1224
zone.js:682 Uncaught Error: permission_denied at /accounts/DKesxlT2mkUwwJGCaHBTkPHuDwl2/slugs: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at G (database.js:230) [<root>]
    at Object.G (database.js:234) [<root>]
    at $g (database.js:218) [<root>]
    at Pg.g.wd (database.js:211) [<root>]
    at Ce.wd (database.js:113) [<root>]
    at cd.Xf (database.js:111) [<root>]
    at fd (database.js:67) [<root>]
    at WebSocket.Ia.onmessage (database.js:66) [<root>]
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as _onmessage] (zone.js:889) [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151) [<root> => <root>]
    at WebSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:345) [<root>]
ZoneAwareError @ zone.js:682
G @ database.js:230
(anonymous) @ database.js:234
$g @ database.js:218
g.wd @ database.js:211
Ce.wd @ database.js:113
(anonymous) @ database.js:111
fd @ database.js:67
Ia.onmessage @ database.js:66
wrapFn @ zone.js:889
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
```

Comment: You've had quite a few similar edits recently; please try to *learn something* from them. For one thing, note that not everybody who might be willing and able to help identifies as a "dude".

Comment: The error is most likely effected by observables that are still subscribed when the logout is initiated.

Comment: FYI..if prior to calling logout I  redirect to the login page then logout  works.  This will then unsubscribe  from the child component.